# Request Header doesn't work for cross-domain Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a parameter in the request header and it works fine for same-domain calls, but if I call a different domain (the API) I need to change the header param itself.

This is the code I've tried to add a parameter.

```
jqXHR.setRequestHeader(
  "Authorization", 'bearer t-7614f875-8423-4f20-a674-d7cf3096290e'
);
```

Should be like this

```
Authorization: bearer t-3e57cc74-3e7a-4fc7-9bbb-f6c83252db01
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

But for cross-domain calls it becomes like this:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers  authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method   GET
```

Can anyone give me any idea how to fix this for cross-domain calls?

Comment: this has been asked many many times

Comment: sorry for creating it again, but I couldn't find any helpful solution and I'm stuck over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the ["preflighting"](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests) part of CORS since you use custom headers. There is a good documentation on it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

You basically need to handle a HTTP `OPTIONS` request and respond with the proper headers indicating the client that the request is allowed. If you simply want to allow all GET requests with the `Authorization` header the following response headers would do the job:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm using jquery library for request, can I use that or I've have to use a custom function for requesting

Comment: It is **not** a JS thing. Using jQuery is perfectly fine. You just need to do what I mentioned on the server side.